# Object required: play.api.mvc.Result error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I want to secure my app with this

```
def Secured[A](username: String, password: String)(action: Action[A]) = Action(action.parser) { 
 request =>   request.headers.get("Authorization").flatMap { authorization =>
    authorization.split(" ").drop(1).headOption.filter { 
       encoded => new String(org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(encoded.getBytes)).split(":").toList match {
        case u :: p :: Nil if u == username && password == p => true
        case _ => false
      }
    }.map(_ => action(request))   }.getOrElse {
    Unauthorized.withHeaders("WWW-Authenticate" -> """Basic realm="Secured"""")   } }
```

But at `getOrElse` part,  I'm getting the following error:

> type mismatch; found : Object required: play.api.mvc.Result

What is wrong?

Comment: Look at the types returned by each code block. Scala infers Object because they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trouble here that `action(request)` is returning `Future[Result]` not just `Result`. So type of whole expression before `getOrElse` is `Option[Future[Result]]` and it awaits `Future[Result]` as parameter to `getOrElse`.

So at first you can wrap your `Unauthorized.withHeaders` thing into `Future.successfull( ... )`

Next thing is that result of whole expression then is `Future[Result]` and it's not correct argument type for the `Action.apply(bodyParser)( ... )`, but there is `Action.async` method that could handle it.

So whole corrected block with minimum type corrections \ refactoring is

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

def secured[A](username: String, password: String)(action: Action[A]) =
  Action.async(action.parser) {
    request => request.headers.get("Authorization").flatMap { authorization =>
      authorization.split(" ").drop(1).headOption.filter { encoded =>
        val bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded.getBytes)
        new String(bytes).split(":").toList match {
          case u :: p :: Nil if u == username && password == p => true
          case _ => false
        }
      }.map(_ => action(request))
    }.getOrElse {
      Future.successful(
        Unauthorized.withHeaders(
          "WWW-Authenticate" -> """Basic realm="Secured""""))
    }
  }
```

Further sugar injections could lead to even more readable version:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

def secured[A](username: String, password: String)(action: Action[A]) =
  Action.async(action.parser) { request =>
    val result = for {
      authorization <- request.headers.get("Authorization")
      Array(_, encoded, _*) <- Some(authorization.split(" "))
      bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded.getBytes)
      credentials = new String(bytes).split(":").toList
      List(`username`, `password`) <- Some(credentials)
    } yield action(request)

    result.getOrElse {
      Future.successful(
        Unauthorized.withHeaders(
          "WWW-Authenticate" -> """Basic realm="Secured""""))
    }
  }
```

Note that unpacking in the left hand side of `<-` is transformed to `filter` with `match`